# Do variables in a parent abstract class get inherited by the child class?

Tags: java, abstract-class

Okay so will each instance of a subclass i.e. a J_Tetrimino class which extends Tetrimino get its own int[][] UP and String orientation?

```
public abstract class Tetrimino {

// [row][col]

/*The size of the area a tetrimino needs*/
protected final int TETRIMINO_SPACE_SIZE = 3;

/*The upwards and initial orientation of the J tetrimino*/
protected int[][] UP;

/*The left and second orientation of the J tetrimino*/
protected int[][] LEFT;

/*The down and third orientation of the J tetrimino*/
protected int[][] DOWN;

/*The right and fourth orientation of the J tetrimino*/
protected int[][] RIGHT;

protected String orientation = "UP";

public String getCurrentOrientation() {
    return orientation;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Every instance of a concrete implementation of your posted abstract class will get its' own instance of those fields. None of them are `static` which would make them shared. Also, all of them are `protected` so they will be visible in the sub-class (unless they're shadowed).

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I wanted to know!